# Casting Dates and Rounding

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, casting

I am trying to figure out the age of individuals when they graduate by using their graduation date and their birthdate. When trying to cast the parameters as dates, however, I get the error:

"No matching signature for operator - for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: INT64 - INT64; NUMERIC - NUMERIC; BIGNUMERIC - BIGNUMERIC; FLOAT64 - FLOAT64; DATE - INT64; DATE - DATE; TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP; DATETIME - DATETIME; TIME - TIME; TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL; DATE - INTERVAL; DATETIME - INTERVAL; INTERVAL - INTERVAL at [7:9]"

Below is the code that I am using.

```
select
  INDEX she_mpi,G_CIP, G_IPEDS, MAX(G_DATE) G_DATE,G_YEAR,

  GENDER, G_ETHNIC_H, G_ETHNIC_A, G_ETHNIC_B, G_ETHNIC_I, G_ETHNIC_P, G_ETHNIC_W,
  G_ETHNIC_N, G_ETHNIC_U,

  round(cast(g_date as date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') - cast(G_BIRTH_DT as date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') )/365.25 as age_at_grad, 
  row_number() over(partition by INDEX order by G_YEAR desc) as rn


from `she.she_graduation_di`

group by MASTER_PERSON_INDEX, g_cip, g_ipeds, g_year, GENDER, G_ETHNIC_H, G_ETHNIC_A, G_ETHNIC_B, G_ETHNIC_I, G_ETHNIC_P, G_ETHNIC_W,
  G_ETHNIC_N, G_ETHNIC_U
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following which seemed to work for me with no similar error to what you described:

```
WITH Roster AS
 (SELECT 'Adams' as LastName, '1967-08-20' as birth, '2021-09-12' as grad UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Buchanan', '1986-02-14' as birth, '2016-01-14' as grad UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Coolidge', '1999-12-31' as birth, '2021-09-12' as grad UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Davis', '1992-06-06' as birth, '2021-09-12' as grad UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Eisenhower', '1977-07-04' as birth, '2021-09-12' as grad)
SELECT LastName, DATE_DIFF(cast(grad as date), cast(birth as date), DAY)/365.25 as age FROM Roster
```